# Check permission for user location

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

I have been following the Android Developers tutorial for getting the user's last known location: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. I followed the steps and got the following error: `Call requires permissions which may be reject by the user: code should explicitly check to see if the permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException`.

After researching this a bit I decided to create a checkPermissions method to check for the permissions, however I am still getting the same error mentioned above.

**Permissions in Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**The getLocation Method**

```
public class ImageGalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    // Instance variables
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 2987;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 7829;
    private static final int REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 200;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this.getActivity());

        checkPermissions(this.getContext());

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this.getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logic to handle location object
                    }
                }
    }

    ...
}
```

**The checkPermissions method**

```
public class ImageGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    private void checkPermissions(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // Access coarse location permission check
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Check if explanation required
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this.getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                // Provide explanation
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Access coarse location permission is necessary to save location to images");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            else {
                // No explanation required, request permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        }


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Reading external storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Writing external storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

        }

    }
}

    ...


}
```

Comment: Did you add location permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @hardartcore yes, just edited my question to include manifest permissions

Comment: Sorry I just saw....you are doing it wrong. You are checking for permissions state, but you actually doesn't really care if you can use the location or not and directly call 'getLastLocation'. You have a few options here, but you can try to edit 'checkPermissions' and make it return boolean (if permission is already granted or not) and if it's true then try to get the last location.

Comment: Ah okay, how would I create a boolean checkLocationPermission() method to return true upon the permission being granted though?

Comment: 'ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission' is already doing that. It returns if your app can use the location or not. Maybe returning a boolean from that method is not a really good option, it is just an idea. You can create different scenarios how to handle correctly that situation : ) It all depends on you

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented the check permission code but you have got it wrong. here is the road map to do in good way.,

1. When the fragment/activity is start ask for the Location from user or on the action where you need to access the user location.
2. When user grant the location permission then fetch location (only in this condition else you will get error as you indicated in question)
3. When user will allow you the location permission , then you can get its result in **@Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
   switch (requestCode) {**

I strongly believe that you are getting error in the following line

```
 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this.getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logic to handle location object
                    }
                }
```

so you have to show user that you have to allow location to keep application in work, if that permission is necessary you can show RequestPermissionRationale dialog , if he cancel it , you can simply quit the activity.

also I have seen that you have no clear concept on how to request runtime permission. I have seen that you have checked all permission at once.

This is not right way. For different permissions you have to ask one by one. for example you can ask for location , if it is too much necssary for app and if user did not allow it you can quit activity or in case user permit it , you can continue to ask for Read/Write external storage permission.

so this is the flow of requesting permissions. here is a [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/) to see how he is getting permission. Here you can see multiple permission in this tutorial.